# How can I check if the scale of an object is bigger (or smaller) than.......?

Tags: unity, c#

When starting the game, I make the size of the object random. And when I start the game, how can I check if the object's size is smaller than x-1, y-1, and the z doesn't matter. When I try something I get this error: 'non-invocable member 'Vector3' cannot be used like a method.'

Here is the if statement that the error is in:

```
if(transform.localScale < Vector3(1, 1, 1))
{

}
```

I also forgot to mention that the `if` statement is at the end of the start method.

Comment: This error message is telling you that you're trying to "call" Vector3 like it's a function. It looks like you meant to construct a new Vector3, but you're missing a "new" keyword for that. But more importantly, there's no less-than/greater-than relation defined on vectors, so it's unclear what you want this code to do. If localScale is (0.9, 1.1, 1), should that return true because the x is smaller, or false because y is bigger, or true because the volume 0.9*1.1*1=0.99 is less than the volume 1*1*1=1? Clarify your desired logic first, then we can help you translate that logic to correct code

Comment: what I meant was to get the object's size, and check if its size is smaller than 1 on each axis and if it is, then destroy that object. My approach to doing it the way I did was probably wrong and a bit confusing.

Comment: So, presumably you tried the obvious thing of `if (transform.localScale.x < 1 && transform.localScale.y < 1)`, right? Did anything go wrong when you did that?

Comment: I actually just tried that right now and it worked. I didn't think of doing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `if(transform.localScale.x < 1 && transform.localScale.y < 1)` instead of `transform.localScale < Vector3(1, 1, 1)` Which seemed to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors can not be compared directly, but you can compare their `.magnitude`.

Or alternatively, if you always set the x and y component of those scales to the same, you can just compare one of those. This would be slightly faster, because you don't need to calculate the magnitudes.

Comment: theres no need to do that. local scale worked just perfectly and I didn't want to use vectors, that was a slight mistake.

Comment: @DavidA_ localScale **is** a vector.

Comment: I meant that I didn't need to use vector3 or vector2

Comment: @DavidA_ `localScale` **is** a `Vector3` 